# Why this websocket server does not broadcast to connected client?

Tags: go, websocket

Below code is a websocket broadcast server that read from a specific connection then broadcasting it to connected clients.

But this server does not broadcast despite there is no error and warnings.
Why this server does not broadcast?

In this code `self.KabucomConn` is origin socket so read from this socket, then broadcast to client which stored in `Hub.RClients`.

When new connection established, passing connection object with register channel to `Hub`, then `Hub` adds a client to `RClient` that stored client object.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/gorilla/websocket"
)

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}

type Client struct {
    hub  *Hub
    Conn *websocket.Conn
    Send chan []byte
}

func (self *Client) writepump() {
    for {
        select {
        case message := <-self.Send:
            w, err := self.Conn.NextWriter(websocket.TextMessage)
            if err != nil {
                log.Print("writepump: nextwriter error")
            }
            w.Write(message)
            w.Close()
        }
    }
}

type Hub struct {
    RClients    map[*Client]bool
    KabucomConn *websocket.Conn
    register    chan *Client
    unregister  chan *Client
    kabucomchan chan []byte
    url         url.URL
}

func (self *Hub) KabucomRun() {
    for {
        _, b, err := self.KabucomConn.ReadMessage() // read data from origin data connection
        log.Println("read message")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            self.KabucomConn.Close()
            for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ { //retry re-connect up to 5 times
                self.KabucomConn, _, err = websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(self.url.String(), nil)
                if i >= 5 && err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                } else if err != nil {
                    log.Println(err, "try", i)
                    continue
                } else {
                    break
                }
            }
            log.Println("conti")
            continue
        }
        log.Println(b)
        self.kabucomchan <- b
    }
}

func (self *Hub) Run() {
    defer func() {
        for c, _ := range self.RClients {
            close(c.Send)
            c.Conn.Close()
        }
    }()
    for {
        select {
        case message := <-self.kabucomchan:
            log.Println("kabucomchan")
            log.Println(message)
            for c, _ := range self.RClients {
                c.Send <- message
            }
        case c := <-self.register:
            log.Println("reg")
            self.RClients[c] = true

        case c := <-self.unregister:
            log.Println("unreg")
            delete(self.RClients, c)
            close(c.Send)
        }
    }
}

func newHub() *Hub {
    u := url.URL{Scheme: "ws", Host: "192.168.1.8:20063", Path: "/ws"}
    var conn *websocket.Conn
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        d, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial(u.String(), nil)
        if err != nil && i < 5 {
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        } else if i >= 5 {
            log.Println("Hub: Kabucom connection error")
        }
        conn = d
        break
    }
    return &Hub{RClients: make(map[*Client]bool), register: make(chan *Client), KabucomConn: conn}
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, hub *Hub) {
    conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    client := &Client{Conn: conn, hub: hub, Send: make(chan []byte, 256)}
    go client.writepump()
    hub.register <- client
}

func main() {
    hub := newHub()
    go hub.Run()
    go hub.KabucomRun()
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        handler(w, r, hub)
    })
    log.Println(":20021/ws")
    http.ListenAndServe(":20021", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not initializing `Hub.kabucomchan`.

```
func newHub() *Hub {
    //...
    return &Hub{RClients: make(map[*Client]bool), register: make(chan *Client), KabucomConn: conn, /* kabucomchan ??? */}
}
```

Send and receive operations on channels assume that both sender `c<-`  and receiver `<-c` hold a reference to the same channel, but when the channel is `nil` this reference doesn't exist, and the send and receive just block forever.

Properly initialize the channel in the `Hub` constructor:

```
return &Hub{
   RClients: make(map[*Client]bool), 
   register: make(chan *Client), 
   KabucomConn: conn,
   kabucomchan: make(chan []byte, /* buffered? */), // <--- !
}
```

Comment: Is there a compiler setting to raise a warning when detect uninitialized channel?

Comment: @KiYugadgeter `go vet` doesn't detect it